# jurabib, I only want to show "ibid. (as in no.*)"

Tags: bibtex, citing, jurabib

I cited once in page 1.
[image: firstpage for the first time cited]

When I cite the same article in page 2, it keeps showing the full title. This takes a lot of space when I have a lot of citations. I would like to only have "Authors, ibid.(as in n.1)."
[image: Page2]

I realized this occurs when it's the same author. But I have to keep the citations from the same author. How can I get rid of the part blue line covered?

Here is my code

```
 \documentclass[11pt,BCOR=8mm]{scrbook}
  %basic setting
  \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
  \usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
  \usepackage[english]{babel}

  %citations
  \usepackage[
  authorformat=abbrv,authorformat==reducedifibidem,
  authorformat=year,
  citefull=first,
  human,
  bibformat=compress
  bibformat=nohang
  colastsep=divis,
  chicago=true,
  crossref=short,
  pages=format,
  pages=test,
  titleformat=comma,
  ibidem=strict,
  ibidem=name,%&title
  idem=strict,
  howcited=compare,
  lookat,
  superscriptedition=all,
  ]{jurabib}

  \begin{document}

  This is the first time I cite this article. \footcitetitle{bibexample1}

  This the second citation. \footcitetitle{bibexample2}


  \newpage

  This is the second time I cite this article, but I do not want to repeat the title. \footcitetitle{bibexample1} Now the second citation comes again. \footcitetitle{bibexample2}

  \bibliographystyle{jox}
  \bibliography{jurabibtesting}

  \end{document}
  }
```

And here is the .bib file

```
  @article{bibexample1,
    title = {This is how to simplify the repeated citations},
    author = {Mr Martin and Mr Steve and Mr Crain},
    journal = {J. jurabib testing},
    volume = {1},
    issue = {11},
    pages = {58},
    numpages = {5},
    year = {2016},
  }

  @article{bibexample2,
    title = {It just keeps reapting the titel},
    author = {Mr Martin and Mr Steve and Mr Crain},
    journal = {J. jurabib testing},
    volume = {4},
    issue = {22},
    pages = {598},
    numpages = {4},
    year = {2015},
  }
```

Comment: You want the subsequent citation to read `Idem (2015), ibid. (as in n. 2)`?! That seems a little redundant and not a little confusing. "Idem" means "the same (person)" and ibid. = ibidem, which means "in the very same place" (conventionally, these refer to the previous citation) -- so you're saying "the same person, in the very same place [but] as in note 2". People might be surprised to learn that the same place is the journal rather than the title.

Comment: Either way, you may find `biblatex` is more flexible than `jurabib`.